# Verify the file is exist on a location in jmeter using beanshell

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, file-exists

I am trying to validating that a particular file exists or not in a folder using BeanShell sampler in jmeter.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String filename;
String tempFile;

if(vars.get("LogFile") != null) 
    {
    filename = vars.get("LogFile");
    log.info("File exist");
    }
else {
    log.info("File exist");
    }
```

I have defined ***LogFile*** in user-defined variable. And it is defined as 
LogFile : D:\Jmeter\Jmeter.log,
currently, it is always returning true because it is not validating whether the file really exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check you need to add a file exists check

```
if (new File(filename).exists()) { 
    log.info("File exist");
} else {
    log.info("File not exist");
}
```

Comment: _user7294900_: if the file not exists, how to create on the fly.

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883474/how-to-write-data-to-csv-in-jmeter-using-beanshell-scripting

Answer (score 1):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so I would recommend forgetting about Beanshell.

The relevant code to check whether the file exists or not and if it doesn't - create it would be something like:

```
File file = new File(vars.get("LogFile"));

if (file.exists()) {
    log.info("File exists");
} else {
    log.info("File doesn't exist, creating...")
    file.createNewFile()
}
```